# problems with installing matplotlib on windows

Tags: windows, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib on windows but there is an error:

```
* The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                            * freetype
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png
```

although I have installed both through the pip install command:

```
C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip install freetype-py
Requirement already satisfied: freetype-py in c:\users\andrzej\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.2.1)

C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip install pypng
Requirement already satisfied: pypng in c:\users\andrzej\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.0.18).
```

I will be grateful for your help. Best

Answer (score 0):

The freetype and libpng packages listed in the error message are C libraries that need to be installed on your system for matplotlib to build against.  Unfortunately freetype-py and pypng are quite separate from the C libraries and don't provide the files that matplotlib needs.

As you probably don't want to compile these two libraries yourself your best option is to install matplotlib by using a binary wheel, which will include the missing files.

Wheels are built for the latest stable versions of Python, and are usually used by pip when they are available.  Unless you have a particular reason to run a release candidate version of Python you'll find package installation in general has fewer problems by switching to the latest stable release (3.6 at the time of writing).  Then `pip install matplotlib` should be all you need.

If you must use the release candidate you can download wheels built for it from [Christoph Gohlke's unofficial packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib).

Comment: Thank for a help I going to try this

Comment: I have one more question are all versions 3.6.... stable I mean for example 3.6.5 or is it only 3.6.0?

Comment: @AndrzejMolenda Yes, generally you would use the most recent version of your chosen release. So, if you're using the 3.6 release the most recent version is 3.6.6 (just been made available). Upgrading between these minor versions rarely causes issues as language features stay the same, a program that runs on 3.6.1 should run unchanged on 3.6.6 (and, unless you're doing something obscure would probably run on anything back to 3.0).

Comment: @AndrzejMolenda Ironically 3.7 has just become the newest major release, so eventually wheels for this version will become more widely available.  However, right now 3.6 is the most recent release with a [matplotlib wheel](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files).